# In terms of performance, which is better Flex or Silverlight?

Tags: apache-flex, silverlight, performance

In general, which performs better?  How are they like when processing vector graphics?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Bubblemark](http://bubblemark.com/) is the premier benchmarking site for RIA.

Note at least one comparison image [showing better drawing](http://www.hot-keyboard.com/dk/FvsSL.png) in Flash.

The [GUIMark](http://www.craftymind.com/guimark/) test is very interesting, the initial results showing SilverLight performance as poor. If you read down into the comments, the solution was identified as being partly a coding problem with timing and partly due to a major speed issue with SilverLight rendering text.

So, one key issue would be if text forms a major part of what you wish to render at speed.

Aside - I did a realtime graphing engine in Cocoa back in 2003 where I ended up using traditional Quickdraw rendering because the heavily anti-aliased and fancy text rendering of the Quartz graphics on Mac OS/X at the time was way too slow. Fast, good-looking text is not easy!

Comment: The latest bubblemark galleries show a significant improvement for Silverlight.  On my machine in Chrome the silverlight bubblemark runs around 260fps.